# The Cartesian product of an infinite number of sets each containing at least two elements is either empty or infinite?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_set) it is written:

> The Cartesian product of an infinite number of sets each containing at least two elements is **either empty or infinite**; if the axiom of choice holds, then it is infinite.

How can one prove that it is either empty or infinite?

My idea is that you assume it is finite but non-empty, and then consider its cartesian product with a set of at least two elements and come up with a contradiction, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Note that the definition of infinite is that for every natural number there is a subset that bijects to it.

Comment: If the product is nonempty, then for any finite subset of the index set of the product, you can change the values of the product element on that finite set of indices.  So, for all $n$, the cardinality of the product is at least $2^n$.  (Without AC, though, I don't immediately see how you could get a single injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the product.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler You don't need an injection from $\Bbb N$. According to the definition of infinite given by the OP, your method is fine

Comment: @DanielSchepler "injection from $\Bbb N$ to the product" is Dedekind-infinite, which is not equivalent to the definition I gave you if you don't assume AC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f\in\prod_{i\in I} A_i$, where $I$ is infinite and each $A_i$ has at least two elements. We want to show that $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ is infinite.

To do this, fix some injection $h:\{1, 2, ..., n\}\rightarrow I$. Since each $A_i$ has at least two elements, we can find a tuple $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ with $a_k\in A_{h(k)}$ and $f(h(k))\not=a_k$. *(Note that the existence of such a tuple [does **not** require choice](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32545/8133), since we're just making finitely many choices here. And this is the only choice-flavored step in the proof.)*

Now for $k\in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, let $f_k$ be given by

- $f_k(h(k))=a_k$, and
- if $i\not=h(k)$, then $f_k(i)=f(i)$.

That is, to build $f_k$ we start with $f$ and change the $h(k)$th coordinate to $a_k$.

Clearly the $f_k$ are distinct, so the map $k\mapsto f_k$ is an injection from $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ into the product $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$. Since this works for all $n$, the latter is infinite.

Comment: There have been so many threads on *this* site discussing finite choices, why link to MO? :)

Comment: [Note that in the first step it is assumed that $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I}A_i$ is non-empty, which may not be the case without the axiom of choice.]

Comment: @KennyLau Remember the goal is to show that the product is either empty or infinite - I'm starting by assuming it's not empty, and then concluding that it's infinite. So I'm not secretly using choice anywhere, here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I did not intend to mean so.